# Assigning Joomla Search Module to Search Specific Pages

Tags: joomla2.5

On my Joomla site I have a search module that searches through the whole site. I would like to create a user-guide section within my website and add a secondary search function to search ONLY the pages I have created for the user-guide.

I thought maybe I could assign article id's to a search module but I can't see a way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a setting for this but I can't remember it being there. You can look for an extension that supports category selection or you can customize the standard module by checking if the results come from a specific category, if not then you don't show them. Hope this gets you on your way.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll have another look at the Joomla extensions but Ideally it's a freebie I'd be looking for.

Comment: I had a look for you and found a free extension that offers this possibility: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search-a-indexing/site-search/16381

Comment: Thanks you soooo much. You've been a brilliant help :)

Comment: If your question is answered then you can select the checkmark on the left of the answer which answered your question. This is so others can see that your question has been answered. Good luck with the extension.